# How to Query Live ODBC data?

Tags: sql, odbc

Hoping you can please assist.

The company I work for backs up their live database to a data warehouse - both can be queried via Excel using SQL syntax via an ODBC connector (Data - Get Data - From Other Sources - From ODBC).

Sometimes there is a lag between the live data and the DWH. I'm looking to identify this faster simply by counting the rows of live data vs. data warehouse.

I found the below code which works extremely well on **only** the data warehouse:

```
SELECT SUM(p.rows) FROM sys.partitions AS p
  INNER JOIN sys.tables AS t
  ON p.[object_id] = t.[object_id]
  INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
  ON s.[schema_id] = t.[schema_id]
  WHERE t.name = N'CONLINW'
  AND s.name = N'dbo'
  AND p.index_id IN (0,1);
```

When I use that same code in the live data, I receive the following "Syntax Error" relating to the table name:

[SQL Syntax Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFHVM.jpg)

I'm hoping someone with a bit more knowledge relating to this issue may be able to assist - I have no idea why this code works fine the in data warehouse, but not the live data. Ususally code is interchangable between these DSN's, so I'm hoping its something simple.

Thanks in advance.

Tried to run a query in live data that works fine in the DWH, with no luck. Resulted in syntax error.

Comment: it seems that your live database does not support the `N'...'` syntax to indicate a unicode/wide character set literal; do you know what technology is used there?